# How do i render my world and entities properly and setting up my Camera with the viewport right?

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

I was messing around with Scene2D and Screen Caches and was wondering what I did wrong. Before I introduced Scene2D to my project everything worked fine. I have a Loading Screen which loads the assets I need for my game with a Scene2D LoadingScreenUI to show the user a progressbar. As far as I know everything with the loading is working.
Now I tried the exact same setup with my MainGameScreen and its MainGameUI, so my world and my entities like the player and the monsters are loaded and visible on the screen + the UI of the MainGameScreen, which is currently a test output.
It could be that I made something wrong with my camera or the viewport.

[image: The current result of my game, after its started and the loading of the assets is done]

The screen should have a classic orthographic tilemap with three diffrent tile types, one player and two monsters, but instead its all black.

[image: How the game should look (this is a picture of my main branch without the experimental code)]

```
public abstract class AbstractScreen<T extends Table> implements Screen {
    protected final SafeHumankindGame context;
    protected final T screenUI;
    protected final Stage stage;
    protected ExtendViewport extendViewport;
    
    public AbstractScreen( SafeHumankindGame context ) {
        this.context = context;
        extendViewport = context.getExtendViewport();
        stage = context.getStage();
        screenUI = getScreenUI( context.getSkin() );
    }
    
    protected abstract T getScreenUI( final Skin skin );
    

    @Override
    public void show() {
        stage.addActor( screenUI );
    }
    

    @Override
    public void resize( final int width, final int height ) {
        extendViewport.update( width, height );
        stage.getViewport().update( width, height, true );
    }
    

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        stage.getRoot().removeActor( screenUI );
    }
    
}
```

```
public class MainGameUI extends Table {
    public MainGameUI( final Skin skin ) {
        super( skin );
        setFillParent( true );
        
        
        add( new TextButton( "Blub", skin, "huge" ) );
        setDebug( true, true );
    }
}
```

```
public class MainGameScreen extends AbstractScreen<MainGameUI> {
    private static final String TAG = SafeHumankindGame.class.getSimpleName();
    private ExtendViewport extendViewport;
    private WorldGenerator worldRen;
    private Entity player;
    private Entity rangedMonster;
    private Entity meeleMonster;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    
    
    public MainGameScreen( final SafeHumankindGame context ) {
        super( context );
        extendViewport = context.getExtendViewport();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        extendViewport.setCamera( camera );
        worldRen = new WorldGenerator( context );
        player = new Player( context, this );
        rangedMonster = new RangedMonster( context, this );
        meeleMonster = new MeeleMonster( context, this );
    }
    
    
    @Override
    protected MainGameUI getScreenUI( Skin skin ) {
        return new MainGameUI( skin );
    }
    

    @Override
    public void show() {
    
    }
    

    @Override
    public void render( float delta ) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
        Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
        if( Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed( Input.Keys.ESCAPE ) ) {
            context.setScreen( ScreenType.MENUE );
        }
        extendViewport.apply();
        context.getSpriteBatch().setProjectionMatrix( extendViewport.getCamera().combined );
        context.getSpriteBatch().begin();
        worldRen.drawGround( context.getSpriteBatch() );
        player.render( delta, context.getSpriteBatch() );
        rangedMonster.render( delta, context.getSpriteBatch() );
        meeleMonster.render( delta, context.getSpriteBatch() );
        context.getSpriteBatch().end();
        camControls();
        player.update();
        rangedMonster.update();
        meeleMonster.update();
        extendViewport.getCamera().position.y = player.getPosition().y + ( player.getEntityDimension().y / 2 );
        extendViewport.getCamera().position.x = player.getPosition().x + ( player.getEntityDimension().x / 2 );
        camera.update();
    }
```

The brain of my Game is the SafeHumankindGame class. Here im loading and initializing the skin and setting my screens:

```
public class SafeHumankindGame extends Game {
    private static final String TAG = SafeHumankindGame.class.getSimpleName();
    private final float WIDTH = 1280;
    private final float HEIGHT = 720;
    private ExtendViewport extendViewport;
    private float myDelta;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private AssetManager assetManager;
    private Skin skin;
    private EnumMap<ScreenType, AbstractScreen> screenCache;
    private Stage stage;
    
    public AssetManager getAssetManager() {
        return assetManager;
    }
    
    public void setAssetManager( AssetManager assetManager ) {
        this.assetManager = assetManager;
    }
    
    public float getWIDTH() {
        return WIDTH;
    }
    
    public float getHEIGHT() {
        return HEIGHT;
    }
    

    @Override
    public void create() {
        Gdx.app.setLogLevel( Application.LOG_DEBUG );
        
        //initialize assetManager
        assetManager = new AssetManager();
        assetManager.setLoader( TextureAtlas.class, new TextureAtlasLoader( assetManager.getFileHandleResolver() ) );
        assetManager.setLoader( Texture.class, new TextureLoader( assetManager.getFileHandleResolver() ) );
        
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        extendViewport = new ExtendViewport( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
        
        initSkin();
        // window height and width
        stage = new Stage( extendViewport, spriteBatch );
        myDelta = 0.0f;
        
        
        //init first screen
        screenCache = new EnumMap<ScreenType, AbstractScreen>( ScreenType.class );
        setScreen( ScreenType.LOADING );
    }
    
    public Stage getStage() {
        return stage;
    }
    
    public Skin getSkin() {
        return skin;
    }
    
    public ExtendViewport getExtendViewport() {
        return extendViewport;
    }
    
    private void initSkin() {
        final ObjectMap<String, Object> resources = new ObjectMap<String, Object>();
        final FreeTypeFontGenerator fontGenerator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator( Gdx.files.internal( "ui/font.ttf" ) );
        final FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter fontParameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        fontParameter.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
        fontParameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
        final int[] sizesToCreate = { 16, 20, 26, 32 };
        for( int size : sizesToCreate ) {
            fontParameter.size = size;
            resources.put( "font_" + size, fontGenerator.generateFont( fontParameter ) );
        }
        fontGenerator.dispose();
        
        //load skin
        final SkinLoader.SkinParameter skinParameter = new SkinLoader.SkinParameter( "ui/hud.atlas", resources );
        assetManager.load( "ui/hud.json", Skin.class, skinParameter );
        assetManager.finishLoading();
        skin = assetManager.get( "ui/hud.json", Skin.class );
    }
    
    public SpriteBatch getSpriteBatch() {
        return spriteBatch;
    }
    
    public void setScreen( final ScreenType screenType ) {
        final Screen screen = screenCache.get( screenType );
        if( screen == null ) {
            try {
                Gdx.app.debug( TAG, "Creating new screen: " + screenType );
                final AbstractScreen newScreen = ( AbstractScreen ) ClassReflection.getConstructor( screenType.getScreenClass(), SafeHumankindGame.class ).newInstance( this );
                screenCache.put( screenType, newScreen );
                setScreen( newScreen );
            }
            catch( ReflectionException e ) {
                throw new GdxRuntimeException( "Screen " + screenType + " could not be created", e );
            }
        }
        else {
            Gdx.app.debug( TAG, "Switching to new screen: " + screenType );
            setScreen( screen );
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        spriteBatch.dispose();
        assetManager.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();
        extendViewport.apply();
        myDelta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        
        stage.getViewport().apply();
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any ErrorMessages and the loggers I build in are all working fine and dont show me anything wrong.
I'm very sure the Entities and the world is rendered somewhere somehow, because when I change the backgound color of the MainGameScreen render method it works. The test output of the GameUI is also visible. When I press WASD, the player is moving, but not visible. I know the player is moving, because my camera is bound to the players positon and the camera moves looking into the nothingness. My Testoutputs of showing me every position of every Tile on the map and the current position of my player is also working and giving me the right data on the console.